# Fine Structure and Fine Structure Constant - intuitive relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, physical-constants

How does the fine structure and fine structure constant relate to each other, intuitively?

I've seen $\alpha$ [extrapolated as a term in energy calculations](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node107.html) for fine structure, but is there a stronger physical intuition for explaining the relation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Physical_interpretations

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but the fine structure of what?